# Setting a Bookmark to array of cells for Named Range in exported xlsx file

Tags: excel, report, birt

In Birt Report, Setting a bookmark to a cell creates a Named range for that cell in the exported Excel file.

```
 For Example:-
      MyBookmark - "MySheet"!D3
```

But, How to set a Bookmark for a list of cells?

```
 For Example:-
      My Bookmark - "MySheet"!D3:D10
```

Does anyone have any idea or any workaround?

**Tried**

I set a bookmark to a detail row, it creates a bookmark with the name I have given but it refers only starting row. but creates new names for each row.So if it is 10 rows 10 bookmarks are created.